# Paraview paraview.plugin purpose

Tags: cmake, plugins, include, vtk, paraview

I am trying to develop a plugin for the ParaView application.
However, I faced that header files are not found, and that's why the build all fails.

It seems that in order to include headers, one should write down the paraview modules being used by the plugin to paraview.plugin file, and the files will be included automatically by Paraview cmake macroses. Am I right?

But for some reason it did not worked.

I ve tried to add directories with include_directories manually, and it worked.

However I face some other files, that are missing

I am convinced that paraview.plugin should be enough  to include all necessary directories and not do it manually

Could one clarify what could be wrong?
Maybe some cache issues?  Where to start?

Answer (score 0):

ParaView itself needs to be manually built in order to build plugins, there is no `sdk`.

To help with that, a docker based solution is provided in this repo https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview-easy-plugin-builder for linux, and a guide for windows is here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview-plugin-windows-binary-compatible-guide

Also an help about developing plugins : https://kitware.github.io/paraview-docs/latest/cxx/PluginHowto.html